# Jquery select div value

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="testdiv">1</div>
```

Hi guys i wanna select testdiv value  1  .

Example:

var testdiv = ('.testdiv').val(); = this variable to need equal 1.

Comment: Both answers below are correct, but you should have a basic knowledge of how jQuery works.   Have you included jQuery on your page?  Do you know that jQuery functions should have `$` in front of them?  Etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for this, it's very basic.

```
var testdiv = $('.testdiv').html();
```

Or

```
var testdiv = $('.testdiv').text();
```

`.val()` is for input elements.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayzn/)**

And be sure to wrap your code in:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or place the code after the element has been rendered to the page.

Comment: i wanna select value 1 is variable i cant  write ('1')

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: His comment means that in your original answer, you were setting the value to 1, not reading the value in the div :)   Your updated answer, however, is correct.

Comment: var x = $('. testdiv').text(); = undefined i need : 1

Comment: It's not undefined, see the fiddle. Make sure your code is run after the element exists on the page. jsFiddle wraps jQuery code in a document.ready call by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `$` in front of your function for jQuery...
You also want to use text() and not val().

Like so...

`var testdiv = $('.testdiv').text();`

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/BUpxw/